Boundary hitting and arbitrage in Reflecting Brownian Motion approximation
I am facing the following quantitative finance problem.
Suppose that $z$ follows a Brownian Motion centered at $0$. There are two boundaries that define a no-arbitrage region: $[-b,b]$. Trades take place according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Each time a trade occurs, e.g. at time $\tau$, if $z_\tau < -b$ an arbitrage profit can be realized according to a function that is differentiable, increasing and convex in the distance from the boundary $f(|  z_\tau -(-b)  |)$. Similarly, if  $z_\tau > b$ the arbitrage profit is $f(z_\tau - b)$. After arbitrage, $z_t$ is brought back on the boundary.
Now, as $\lambda \to \infty$, this model converges to a Browinan motion with two reflecting boundaries at $-b,b$.
Is it correct to say that arbitrage profits in this case are zero because the fraction of time on which the process is on the boundary is zero?
I am not convinced but rather think that each time the boundary is hit, there is a marginal profit to be made. So the asymptotic rate of profits should be something like $f'(0)(\alpha + \beta)$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the rate of boundary hitting for the low and the high boundary respectively, and for a driftless process I conjecture that $\alpha + \beta = \sigma^2/(2b)$
